# Sequelize: how to let the database handle primary key value?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize 6.5.0. I created a simple model to do two rudimentary things: a) find records, b) create records. I'm having trouble creating records; specifically, ones with primary key. If I designate the column as primaryKey like so:

```js
const Table = sequelize.define('table', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  datum: {...}
...
```

and try to create a record like so:

```js
Table.create({datum: 'abc'})
```

then it will try (and fail) to set the primary key with:

```sql
INSERT INTO "table" ("id","datum") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING ...;
```

which is 50% what I did not ask it to do. Now, I don't need this to happen since default value for `id` is already handled at the database level. So, the next natural move was to *not* designate `id` as `primaryKey`:

```js
const Table = sequelize.define('table', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    // primaryKey: true
  },
  datum: {...}
...
```

But now sequelize attempts to get smart and throws a tantrum:

```
Uncaught Error: A column called 'id' was added to the attributes of 'table' but not marked with 'primaryKey: true'
```

Q) ***How do I get sequelize to *NOT* handle primary key on create?***

Answer (score 0):

I think you can skip the `id` field in the definition altogether, and PostgreSQL will still have one

Comment: Definitely crossed my mind but I still want to retrieve the id when querying and I want to get the newly generated id one when INSERT-ing.

Comment: Both of these will be possible - you're getting the id among other fields returning from create, and the id will be accessible when querying

Comment: Yes and no. Sequelize will automatically conjure up a field named `id` that it will automatically treat as an autoincremented integer primaryKey which is at odds with my uuid pk in the real table.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `DataType.UUID`, you have specify some other options, like `defaultValue` and `allowNull`. Here is an example:

```
const Table = sequelize.define('table', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false
  },
  datum: {...}
});
```